# Verificar se o framework 3.5 está instalado na maquina

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, winforms, windows

Tenho de efectuar uma função em C# que verifique se a framework 3.5 esta instalada na maquina mas  sem usar `Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("Software\Windows\Microsoft.NET\...")`, pois esta função ter de ser usada em diversas maquinas diferentes todas elas com caminhos diferentes para a Framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A localização física dos arquivos é diferente do *Registry*. Independente do local onde o .NET foi instalado, uma chave em `Software\\Microsoft\\NET Framework Setup\\NDP\\v3.5` será criada.

O método descrito por você irá funcionar.